# MySQL: Counting column from different tables on a certain timeframe

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(COUNTED) AS TCOUNTED 
    FROM (SELECT COUNTED FROM `clicks`.`t1`
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNTED FROM `clicks`.`t2`
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNTED FROM `clicks`.`t3`
         ) AS TMP
```

Where and how do I add a time constraint? I want it to count only between certain dates... Sorry for the MySQL noobness.

Thanks!

Comment: Do your tables have date columns in them to compare against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(COUNTED) AS TCOUNTED 
    FROM (SELECT COUNTED FROM `clicks`.`t1` WHERE somedatecol BETWEEN somedate AND somedate
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNTED FROM `clicks`.`t2` WHERE somedatecol BETWEEN somedate AND somedate
          UNION ALL
          SELECT COUNTED FROM `clicks`.`t3` WHERE somedatecol BETWEEN somedate AND somedate
         ) AS TMP`
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 2):

I would think your best bet is to include the where clause inside each sub-select before the UNION statements.

```
SELECT SUM(COUNTED) AS TCOUNTED FROM
(SELECT COUNTED FROM clicks.t1 WHERE <fieldname> BETWEEN '<date1>' AND '<date2>'
   UNION ALL
SELECT COUNTED FROM clicks.t2 WHERE <fieldname> BETWEEN '<date1>' AND '<date2>'
   UNION ALL
SELECT COUNTED FROM clicks.t3 WHERE <fieldname> BETWEEN '<date1>' AND '<date2>')
AS TMP;
```

Of course it as all relative to what you are trying to accomplish with the query.